# Parse HTML, write to file

Tags: python, html, parsing, xpath

I have question about parsing HTML tags with python.
My code looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib2
import sys
import re
import time
import urllib
import datetime
def get_web():

    try:
        input_sat = open('rtc.xml','w')
        godina  = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y")
        print godina
        mjesec  = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m")
        print mjesec
        for x in range (32):
            if x < 1:
                x = x + 1
                var = x

                url = 'http://www.rts.rs/page/tv/sr/broadcast/20/RTS+1.html?month={}&year={}&day={}&type=0'.format(mjesec, godina, var)

                page = requests.get(url)
                tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
                a = tree.xpath('//div[@id="center"]/h1/text()') # datum
                b = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramTime"]/text()') # time
                c = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramName"]/text()')
                e = tree.xpath('//div[@class="ProgramName"]/a[@class="recnik"]/text()')


                for line in zip(a,b,c,e):
                    var = line[0]
                    print >> input_sat, line+'\n'




    except:
        pass
get_web()
```

The script works fine and gets tags from a URL, but how can I write them into a file for processing?
When I run my code with a `for` loop, it doesn't work. I don't know where the problem is.

I rewrote my code, it won't output what's on the page to a file.

Comment: Is this your whole code? I tried running it and got `NameError: global name 'logging' is not defined`.

Comment: look into python file i/o e.g. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm (second hit in google)... you just need to open the file, write what you want to it, and close.

Comment: I rewritted my code now, problem is in FOR loop for sercont tags in url, it won't write in file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, your `print()` function is incorrect. You have to use the `write()` function of the handler, and also encode the text to UTF-8:

```
for line in zip(a,b,c,e):
    var = line[0]
    input_sat.write(line[0].encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

It yields:

```
Programska šema - sreda, 01. jan 2014
```

Comment: Yea but there is 3 more tags for parse, and this outputs only one from loop.

Comment: @Fox_01: Just after first loop you have an instruction `if x < 1` that only lets one iteration, and in second loop you use a `zip()` function that takes a number of iterations equals to the min length of all four lists, and as `a` variable has only one element, the loop executes once. Look at it because that has nothing to do on how to write to a file.